# Zurb Foundation Sticky Top Bar and Off-Canvas hiding overlay div

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, off-canvas-menu

I have an issue with Zurb Foundation's combination of Sticky Top Bar, Off Canvas and my use of a *minicart* div on hover.

It seems that my minicart div shows when I hover over the icon but it is covered by the **expanded row** from foundation and will only show above the **expanded row** when the page is moved up by 1px.

The URL is http://dev.turnerandlast.com/

Comment: Can you create a minimal example on [Codeply](http://www.codeply.com/go/p/foundation) or fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

It was a **z-index** issue.

```
.sticky {
    z-index: 1000
}
```